# WPF: How to select which Generic.xaml gets used?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

So I'm using a class library called MyControls.dll in this I have set up a few themes: Generic.xaml (where my controls appear regular), GenericBlue.xaml (where my controls appear blue), etc.

When I use this class library it picks Generic.xaml automatically. My question is can I somehow manually pick which GenericXXX.xaml to pick. I'd like some programs to appear a certain color, and some other programs to appear in another color, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could also manipulate the application's resources at run-time in code and add a xaml file. If you use DynamicResource bindings it will allow you to switch styles/templates at will.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a resource dictionary at Application level out of your themes, as

```
<Application.Resources>
     <ResourceDictionary Source="GenericBlue.xaml"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

If you do this, your control library generic will be ignored, and your application will pick this theme to define the look-and-feel of your controls defined in your library!

Comment: Not quite sure where you mean I'd define this... inside my class library (MyControls.dll) or inside the program that uses it? I'm hoping you don't mean my class library as I'd like it to be configurable...

Comment: @foreyez: I said *Application level*, that obviously means the application program (EXE), not the DLL, since DLL doesn't have Application!